# Tipo de teclado android, texto e número

Tags: android, android-layout, teclado

Tem como eu fazer com que o teclado do android fique com dois tipos, no caso eu queria números e letras. Eu tentei usando `android:inputType`, mas não funcionou. Será que já tem uma forma de resolver isso?

Obrigado.

**RESOLVIDO**

Olhando mais afundo o problema, percebi que o problema não era no tipo de teclado, e sim na máscara do input, tudo que era digitado, na classe da máscara ele chamava o **setText()** fazendo com que o teclado voltasse para o  padrão, então em vez de **setText()**, usei o seguinte:

```
ediText.getText().clear();
ediText.append(mascara.toUpperCase());
```

Obrigado a todos.

Comment: O teclado alfanumerico que aparece não resolve? Basta o usuário apertar a tecla especifica que muda para numeros e simbolos.

Comment: O problema é que quando eu mudo o tipo de teclado, eu clico em um número ele volta pro tipo anterior, talvez pode ser um máscara que estou usando no input, ai quando eu uso o setText, ele volta pro tipo anterior.

Answer (score 3):

Tente o seguinte:

```
android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
```

Segundo a documentação:

> Pode ser combinado com texto e suas variações para solicitar
>   capitalização de todos os caracteres.

Segue o link da [documentação](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)

Saudações